# Nested Routes and Forms in Has Many Through Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a simple Rails4 application. I have **User** model which is generated by Devise GEM, **Examination** model and **Participation** models are both generated by scaffold generator.

These are my models:

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examination
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :examinations, :through => :participations
end
```

Now, I would like to create the structure to make Users to be able to register to exams. In the index page of **Examinations (app/views/examinations/index.html.erb)** I want to add a "Register" button just next to default Show, Edit and Destroy buttons for each exam. When a user clicks to **"Register to Exam"** button I want them to see a page where they can choose their **exam language preference** and then submit their registrations.

Also I want a User can only 1 time register for an exam. They should be able to register for many exams but only 1 time for each.

How can I do this kind of structure? When I'm using nested resources, all my forms are throwing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need nested resources for your forms. Both the exam id and the language preference should be attributes of a participation.

So you just need to build a page to create a new participation, based off of an exam id.

In the Participations controller

```
# if your route is /participations/new?examination_id=1
# you could also do nested routing like /exams/1/participations/new
def new
  @participation = Participation.new
  @examination = params[:examination_id]
end

def create
  @participation = Participation.new params[:participation]
  @participation.user = current_user
    if @participation.save
      redirect_to examinations_page
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

And then it's just a simple form in the new.html.erb page..

```
<h1> Sign up for: <%= @examination.name %> </h1>
<%= form_for @participation do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden :examination_id %>
  <%= f.select :language_preference #add the set of language options in here %>
  <%= f.submit :register %>
<% end %>
```

If you find your form is submitting to the wrong route, then you can set its url.. for example if you have a participation's resources nested under exam's resources, your rough path would be:

```
 <%= form_for @participation, as: :participation, url: new_examination_participation_path(@examination) } do |f| %>
     ...
 <% end %>
```

Comment: **The form:**

`<%= form_for @participation, as: :participation, url: new_examination_participation_path(@participation, @examination) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden :examination_id %>
  <%= f.select :language_preference, options_for_select(["a", "b"]) %>
  <%= f.submit :register %>
<% end %>`

**And the error:**
`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Participations#new 
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"participations", :examination_id=>#<Participation id: nil, user_id: nil, examination_id: nil, language_preference: nil} missing required keys: [:examination_id]`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't thinking earlier. it should just be new_examination_participation_path(@examination). i wrote my answer just by using the shorter "exam" rather than "examination", and wrote the path wrong

Comment: @msdundar are you still getting the same error, or does the updated answer help you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's working good so far, but only I'm having problem with links in the participations/index.html.erb file:

`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_examination_participation_path(participation), :class => 'btn btn-small' %>`
`<%= link_to 'Destroy', examination_participation, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Bla bla' }, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-danger' %>`

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Participations#index
No route matches.

Comment: Good to know it's working @msdundar, would you mind accepting my response as an answer? As for the routes, seems like you just need check if you've written your routes correctly. I think your issue is that you need to pass both the examination and participation into edit_examination_participation_path(participation) (change to something like `edit_examination_participation_path(examination, participation)`).